# Running cron within a docker debian:jessie container

Tags: cron, docker

After installing cron with `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y`, I am unable to run it. if I try run `cron` I get an error saying `cron is not in PATH`. How do I go about using cron within my container?

**Note** The specific container is the official Nginx container provided by docker

**Edit** I am running the command through compose.

Comment: Cron is a daemon ([crond](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html)); as root, you can `/etc/init.d/cron restart` to have it run, but it is running already after you installed it (see `ps auxwww|grep cron`).

Comment: `System error: exec: "/etc/init.d/cron restart": stat /etc/init.d/cron: no such file or directory`

Comment: It should be there. Run `dpkg -l cron`; the last line should print `ii  cron  ....`.

Comment: Busy doing a rebuild - will run that when complete. I did notice this part-way through the setup of cron: `Setting up cron (3.0pl1-127+deb8u1) ...
Adding group `crontab' (GID 108) ...
Done.
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.`

Comment: `dpkg -l cron` returns `dpkg-query: no packages found matching cron`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was building with the docker cli - `docker build .` and running with docker-compose. But compose runs its own build with its own image name attached and so was using an outdated image. `docker-compose build` solved it